# Can you add Firebase to unit tests in a Swift package?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, testing, package

I have a Swift package that implements some read/write methods to Firebase. The package has Firebase correctly set up as a dependency. I can add my Swift package to an iOS project and it works correctly.

Now I want to write some unit tests for the Swift package (an `XCTestCase`) to ensure that the read/write operations are doing what I want.

Is that even possible - can I add Firebase to the tests of a Swift package? Where would you call `FirebaseApp.configure()`? Does a unit test in a swift package even have a bundle ID to generate the `GoogleService-Info.plist`?

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize Firebase with a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file, Firebase parses that file and and the configuration is ultimately handled through a `FirebaseOptions` object. `FirebaseApp.configure(options:)` allows you to pass a custom `FirebaseOptions` object for configuration.

I was able to get Firebase initialized for tests by downloading the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and copying the corresponding values to the following code:

```
final class DemoTests: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {
        let appOptions = FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: "**GOOGLESERVICE-INFO-GOOGLE-APP-ID**",
            gcmSenderID: "**GOOGLESERVICE-INFO-GCM-APP-ID**"
        )
        appOptions.apiKey = "**GOOGLESERVICE-INFO-API-KEY"
        appOptions.projectID = "**GOOGLESERVICE-INFO-PROJECT-ID"
        FirebaseApp.configure(options: appOptions)
    }

    func testSetup() throws { }
}
```